# Nontrivial interpretation of dependent type theory in the category of chain complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

A category $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathbf{Ab})$ of chain complex has a model category structure, which makes the category to interpret dependent type theory.

E.g. a term of a type $A$ is interpreted as an arrow from a terminal object to $A$.

However, there is no nontrivial such arrow because terminal and initial objects coincide in $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathbf{Ab})$.
Doesn't this fact make the interpretation trivial?

Comment: I think you have confused different usages of the word “model” here.

Comment: Could you please make it precise? I think model categories can interpret Martin Löf type theory with identity types. (By "dependent type theory", I meant Martin Löf type theory with identity types.) Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is incorrect, or at least very imprecise. You need a lot more than just a model structure to interpret dependent type theory. For instance you need a locally cartesian closed category, or something very close, to interpret $\Pi$-types.

Comment: By "Martin Löf type theory with identity types", I was thinking of the fragment without Π and Σ.
Then by Thm 3.1. of arxiv.org/pdf/0709.0248.pdf, I think finitely completeness and weak factorization system is enough to model Martin Löf type theory with identity types. Or isn't the stability condition satisfied?

Comment: I suppose if you omit $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$ and $0$ and $+$ you may have a model, yes. But that’s not a very expressive fragment of type theory.